# std::chrono problem, works fine in viusal studio 2019 when I change to 143( Visual Studio 2022 ) it fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

So I am using visual studio 2022 and this is failing to compile.

It works fine in Visual Studio 2019 however.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <format>

//outputs            failed with error code 0x3fe = A notify change request is being completed and the information is not being returned in the caller's buffer. The caller now needs to enumerate the files to find the changes.

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF ); 
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> begin;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> end;
    long long tl1_total{ 0 }, tl2_total{ 0 };
    {
        begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (auto t{ 0 }; t < 100000; t++) {
            std::stringstream dest;
            dest << "\r\nfailed with error code 0x" << std::hex << 1022 << " = " << 
"A notify change request is being completed and the information is not being returned in the caller's buffer. The caller now needs to enumerate the files to find the changes."  << "\r\n Loop counter is " << std::dec << t;
            std::cout << dest.str().c_str();
        }
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        tl1_total = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count());
    }
    {
        begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (auto t{ 0 }; t < 100000; t++) {
            constexpr auto debuginfostr = "\r\nfailed with error code 0x{:x} = {}\r\n Loop counter is {}";
            std::cout << std::format(debuginfostr, 1022, "A notify change request is being completed and the information is not being returned in the caller's buffer. The caller now needs to enumerate the files to find the changes." ,t);
        }
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        tl2_total = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count());
    }
    std::cout << "\r\n time loop one = " << tl1_total << "\r\n time loop two = " << tl2_total << "\r\n And the faster one was ? " << (tl2_total < tl1_total ? "std::format" : "stringstream") << "\r\n";
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

should output 100,000 times - failed with error code 0x3fe = A notify change request is being completed and the information is not being returned in the caller's buffer. The caller now needs to enumerate the files to find the changes.

I was testing to see if I should upgrade from std::ostream to std::format for string formatting for error messages. debugoutputA and logging messages. Simplified a bit.
Seems like std::format is about 20% faster on average. But why doesn't it work in 2022 v143 ?

Comment: What error do you get?  I have VS2022, and it compiles fine for me.

Comment: Unrelated: Why store the `end - begin` result in a `long long` instead of in a `std::chrono::microseconds`?

Comment: I think I found the problem, putting this together for you I found it.  A bit confused how this happened. Probably one of my kids when I was not looking sorry to waste your time. I will just look up  the correct line and fix it sigh oh the problem is - _EXPORT_STD template <class w, class _Duration = typename _Clock::duration> the w should not be there

Comment: how do I mark this solved ?

Comment: Have flagged it for you as caused by a Typo.  I think you can just accept the flag.

Comment: You should have a delete link to just remove the question.

Comment: To "mark this solved" you can post an answer to your own question.  Also, VS2022 defaults to C++14 language standard - this must be bumped to C++20 for this code to compile.

Comment: You could answer and accept it to change the thread's status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)